# How to make authentication REST API calls to Azure App service (Api App)

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to test my App service api app & Authentication using tool such as Fiddler? I used to be able to do this for Mobile Service by passing the token in the request header (x-zumo-auth). But now with App Service, it's no longer working or available.

Reason I ask is that my client won't be limited to those platform or will they be developed using those languages/SDK so I need a way to make REST API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Fiddler, but I have used the Google Chrome Postman extension to do this kind of thing before and it works really well. It is free and you can get it from here (you'll need chrome installed): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop